# Table 'flyway_schema_history' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to use flyway as a migration tool for my existing database using:

**Flyway V5.2.4** & **Mysql V8.0.16**

but when migrating gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from Schema History table `allexpress`.`flyway_schema_history`
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : HY000
Error Code : 1100
Message    : Table 'flyway_schema_history' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from Schema History table `allexpress`.`flyway_schema_history`
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from Schema History table `allexpress`.`flyway_schema_history`
```

Comment: Change the success status to 1 for the specific SQL query in the flyway schema table.

Comment: Not an answer but cannot yet comment (too low a reputation). Is there more than one entry in flyway_schema_history with the same checksum?

Answer (score 5):

I came across this error recently.
Check flyway warnings in the logs. I had the same error message, but the problem came from an insert with a missing value.

Comment: same here! lost in the logs was a SQL syntax error on my migration script

Answer (score 1):

check your DML sql, High probability should be a grammatical error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).